# Show that the cardinality of $\mathbb N$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Show that $| \mathbb N | = | \mathbb N \times \mathbb N |$, i.e., the cardinality  of $\mathbb N$ is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$.

How do I show it using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic and the Schröder–Bernstein Theorem?

Answer (score 0):

You should find injection from each set to other.

Let us first take a look at easy case, an injection $f\colon \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. For instance take $$f(n)=(1,n).$$ Show for exercise it is really an injection.

Now we should find injection $g\colon \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Define $g$ as
$$g(n,m)=2^n3^m.$$ Using fundamental theorem of arithmetic show that this is an injection.

By Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem we get equality.